# JS-IPFS gives low performance compared to IPFS

Tags: javascript, ipfs

I'm using js-ipfs server side to 'upload' files on IPFS, but it seems like it's way less efficient than the command line `ipfs daemon` and `ipfs add someFile`.

Server-side, I instanciate an `Ipfs` object and then I try to `storeData` with a path and the buffer of the content of the file. I am connected to three swarms when my server starts:

```
Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4003/ws/ipfs/QmTBoDWXviw7eRKeDGbp3wU2PxAw1epPxax6mp8uY6CEEW
Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4002/ipfs/QmTBoDWXviw7eRKeDGbp3wU2PxAw1epPxax6mp8uY6CEEW
Swarm listening on /ip4/10.19.77.89/tcp/4002/ipfs/QmTBoDWXviw7eRKeDGbp3wU2PxAw1epPxax6mp8uY6CEEW
```

I use IPFS this way :

```
const IPFS = require('ipfs');
const node = new IPFS();

class Ipfs {

    constructor() {
        node.on('error', e => console.log(e))
        node.on('start', () => console.log('Node started !'))
        node.on('ready', () => console.log('Node is ready !'))
    }

    storeData(content, path) {
        return new Promise((resolve, fail) => {
            let encData = {
                path: path,
                content: content,
            };
            node.files.add(encData, (err, data) => {
                if (err) return fail(err);
                return resolve(data);
            })
        })
    }
}
```

When I call `storeData` from my object, IPFS gives me a hash back where I can get my file, but the `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/[hash]` never loads.

I want to insist on the fact that the hash given by the `ipfs add` command line works instantly

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, in my experience go-ipfs is significantly faster than js-ipfs. So what's the question?

Answer (score 5):

From the command line, when you run `ipfs add <some file>` it will chunk the file, and add it to your local `~/.ipfs` directory. As it runs, it print out the CIDs of the chunks, and finally a root CID.

If you try to fetch a file from IPFS by running `ipfs cat <root CID>` with the CID you just got from running `ipfs add` then it will also be fast as it will be pulling the blocks from your **local** repository. If you run `ipfs cat` with a CID that you dont currently have, then it will ask your connected peers for it. This can take a while if are not currently connected to someone who is providing the data for that CID.

In `js-ipfs` calling `node.files.add` works similarly to running `ipfs add` from the command line. It will return the root CID as soon as it has finished chunking the files and storing them locally (in `~/.jsipfs` by default).

Trying to fetch a root CID from the public gateway via `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/[CID]` can be slow if the IPFS nodes running on the gateway machines operated by ipfs.io take a while to find a provider for that CID. It's a **remote** machine, and it has to first find your local peer that is providing that CID, and fetch the data from them.

When you start up your ipfs node with `ipfs daemon`, the initial output tells you which local network interfaces and ports your nodes is listening on, so

```
Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4003/ws/ipfs/QmTBoDWXviw7eRKeDGbp3wU2PxAw1epPxax6mp8uY6CEEW
Swarm listening on /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4002/ipfs/QmTBoDWXviw7eRKeDGbp3wU2PxAw1epPxax6mp8uY6CEEW
Swarm listening on /ip4/10.19.77.89/tcp/4002/ipfs/QmTBoDWXviw7eRKeDGbp3wU2PxAw1epPxax6mp8uY6CEEW
```

...means that your local ipfs node is listening on the ipv4 addresses `127.0.0.1` and `10.19.77.89`. It doesn't tell you how many peers you have. To find out how many peers you have, run `ipfs swarm peers`

```
$ ipfs swarm peers
/ip4/1.64.206.172/tcp/42707/ipfs/QmUDGjCUDePrxWbpohHLuW8Hy1uGKXi4tJXaN6z7FuNszb
/ip4/100.24.159.221/tcp/46757/ipfs/QmQjGfZq3MvgykH5oXeQaZvU6TGMCD7xtRtUXz1sK4u8nG
/ip4/101.200.58.57/tcp/4001/ipfs/QmRXcRwhbjtgE2E3hF4rRhM3xaGRrjfieUE5iXGCAwrZ9d
...
```

...and to just find the number of peers you are connected to, you can pipe the output into wc -l

```
$ ipfs swarm peers | wc -l
     755
```

*...and in answer to your fundamental question* js-ipfs is only slower than go-ipfs due to the differences in the languages. The are both implementations of the same spec, and they both implement using similar algorithms. If you'd like to use go-ipfs from JS, for any reason, you can do that too, by running a go-ipfs daemon and talking to it via the HTTP API using the [`js-ipfs-http-client`](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-http-client) library which has the same api as [`js-ipfs`](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs)